# Error creating bean with name 'appointmentServiceImpl','appointmentRepository', not a managed type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know there is a lot of questions and answer for problems like this, believe me, I tried to find something usefully for past hour and didn't manage to find anything that will fix this so far.

I will provide entity, repository, and service impl down below and than full stack trace.

`Entity:`

```
@Table(name = "appointment")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Appointment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "date_time")
private LocalDateTime dateTime;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
private Patient patient;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id")
private Doctor doctor;

@Column(name = "reason_for_visit")
private String reasonForVisit;

private String notes;

private String status;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "appointment")
private MedicalRecord medicalRecord;

}
```

`Repo:`

```
@Repository
public interface AppointmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointment, Long> {
```

}

`ServiceImpl:`

```
@Service
public class AppointmentServiceImpl implements AppointmentService {

@Autowired
AppointmentRepository appointmentRepository;

@Override
public List<Appointment> getAllAppointments() {
    return appointmentRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public Appointment getAppointmentById(Long id) {
    return appointmentRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Appointment with ID " + id + " not found."));
}

@Override
public void saveAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
    appointmentRepository.save(appointment);
}

@Override
public void updateAppointment(Long id, Appointment appointment) {
    Appointment existingAppointment = getAppointmentById(id);
    existingAppointment.setPatient(appointment.getPatient());
    existingAppointment.setDoctor(appointment.getDoctor());
    existingAppointment.setReasonForVisit(appointment.getReasonForVisit());
    existingAppointment.setNotes(appointment.getNotes());
    existingAppointment.setStatus(appointment.getStatus());
    existingAppointment.setMedicalRecord(appointment.getMedicalRecord());
    existingAppointment.setDateTime(appointment.getDateTime());
    appointmentRepository.save(existingAppointment);
}

@Override
public void deleteAppointment(Long id) {
    appointmentRepository.deleteById(id);
}
}
```

`StackTrace:`

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appointmentServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'appointmentRepository': Error creating bean with name 'appointmentRepository' defined in com.demo.hospitalmanagementtool.repository.AppointmentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.demo.hospitalmanagementtool.entities.Appointment
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:693) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:482) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at com.demo.hospitalmanagementtool.HospitalManagementTool.main(HospitalManagementTool.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appointmentRepository' defined in com.demo.hospitalmanagementtool.repository.AppointmentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.demo.hospitalmanagementtool.entities.Appointment
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:710) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.demo.hospitalmanagementtool.entities.Appointment
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

**What I tried?**

I tried first with this in my main class:

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com/demo/hospitalmanagementtool/service/impl"})`

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com/demo/hospitalmanagementtool/service"})`

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.demo.hospitalmanagementtool.service.impl"})`

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.demo.hospitalmanagementtool.service"})`

Same errors.

Then I tried this:

`@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.demo.hospitalmanagementtool.entities")`

Same errors.

Comment: Please include the imports/packages you are using in your code, also clarify which Spring Boot version you are using. I suspect you are using Spring Boot 3.0 and added JPA dependencies for JavaEE instead of JakartaEE.

Comment: This is for `spring-boot-starter-parent` : `<version>3.0.6</version>`. Btw. I changed from `import javax.persistence.*;` to `import jakarta.persistence.*;` and now it seems that other errors are solved but I get `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Association 'com.demo.hospitalmanagementtool.entities.Billing.appointment' targets an unknown entity named 'com.demo.hospitalmanagementtool.entities.Appointment'
`

Comment: Please don't add additional information for code, xml etc. as comments as that is totally unreadable. The fact that you have/had `javax.persistence` already means you are trying to outsmart the dependency m anagement. The other error relates to your entitiesw as well you are referncing one that hasn't either `@Entity` or the wrong one.